# Is there anyway to add a sitemap to the Karta platform?

Tags: sitemap

Kartra is hooked to a domain with a CNAME. So my.karta.com resolves to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) -- how is one to add a sitemap? Kartra does not offer that option. And the help seems to be of ...no help.

Tried a sub domain to add the site map to. No go. Tried validating both domains and subdomain. No go.